# Pulling items from dictionary and adding to a new list. (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, del

I am hoping that someone can help me to figure out why this code to add an item from the dictionary to a new list called 'inventory' will not work. This is the error message that I receive: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/filenameblahblahblah", line 71, in 
inventory.append(rooms(current_room['item']))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.
This is for a game that I have to create for class, and this is the only part of the game that isn't working for me. I need to add the 'item' to the list 'inventory' and then remove the 'item' from the dictionary 'rooms'. I apologize in advance if I do not have the sample of the code formatted properly, as I am still learning. Thanks in advance.

`sample of my dictionary`

```
rooms = {
'Cabin A': {'name': 'Cabin A', 'go starboard': 'Stern', 'item': 'Spearhead', 'item name': 'a 
    Spearhead'}, 
'Cabin B': {'name': 'Cabin B', 'go port': 'Hull', 'item': 'Spear Gun', 'item name': 'a Spear 
    Gun'}
        }
```

`sample of what I have so far to try to pull from dictionary to add to list:`

```
current_room = ['Cabin A']
inventory = []
if command in get_items:
    if 'item' in current_room:
        inventory.append(rooms(current_room['item']))
        del rooms[current_room['item']]
        rooms[current_room].update
        print(inventory)
    else:
        print('Nothing here.')
```

Comment: Since `rooms` is a dict, you cannot use `()` to access items. `rooms['Cabin A']['name']` - this is the way to access the `Cabin A` value.

Comment: @ZhongDai That only begins to address the issues in OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

```
if 'item' in current_room:
```

is actually:

```
if 'item' in ['Cabin A']:
```

In other words, you are checking if the string 'item' is part of the list ['Cabin A'], which is not.

Secondly, the part:

```
rooms(current_room['item'])
```

will not work. `rooms` is a dictionary. You cannot call a dictionary `rooms()`, instead you need to do `rooms['Cabin A']`. Therefore, you could instead try:

```
rooms[current_room]['item']
```

where `current_room='Cabin A'`

The following should work:

```
inventory = []
for room in rooms:
    if "item" in rooms[room]:
       inventory.append(rooms[room]["item"])
       rooms[room].pop("item")
       print(inventory)
    else:
       print('Nothing here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are supposed to be accessed like `dict[key]` to get a `value`. Lists are supposed to be accessed like `list[index]` where `index` is an integer representing the index of the list value you're trying to access.

Notice:

```
inventory.append(rooms(current_room['item']))
```

You're using parentheses to access a `rooms` value. You're also trying to access the list `current_room` as if it's a dictionary.